# How to enable facebook, share and embed options in Ooyala V3

Tags: javascript, ooyala

I am using videos from ooyala.com site.I using their javascript api v3.They didn't mention that how to enable facebook or embed options through javascript api v3.

So please help me on this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to Publish tab in backlot and check the share option.

For flash , you can see those buttons in player. (flash-only or flash-priority)

For html5 , you can't see the those buttons in player. (html5-only or html5-priority)

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Flash or HTML5?  For Flash, you can enable this through Backlot.  Share options are not part of our default html5 skin.

Comment: This is just in the Publish tab of Backlot then.